# Polymorphism doesn't work as expected, why?

Tags: java, types, polymorphism, overriding

I have these 2 classes in my java program:

```
public class A {
    private final static A five = new A(5);
    public final int x;
    public A(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return x == ((A) o).x;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return equals(five) ? "five" : (x + "");
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public final int x;
    public B(int x) {
        super(x);
        this.x = x + 1;
    }
    public boolean equals(A o) {
        return x == o.x;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "B: " + super.toString();
    }
}
```

Now in my main i'm doing these 2 simple actions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new A(5));
    System.out.println(new B(5));
}
```

About the first line, as i expected, it will create an A object -> go to A's `toString` function -> get `True` for the `equals` function and finally print "five".

About the B, what i expected and what actually happening is different...
I thought it will go to B's constructor -> go to A constructor and assign the number 5 to `x` -> return to B constructor and assign the number 6 to B's `x` -> go to B's `toString` method and print "B: " (Until this point i was right) -> go to A's `toString` -> go to B's `equals` since the object type is B and that's what you looking at concerning method activation (* This is where i was wrong) -> return `False` because the `x` in B is 6 -> print the number 5 since we were in A's `toString`.

Instead, in the part where it's calling the A class `toString` instead of going to the B `equals` method it's staying in A and activate the A `equals`...

I have no idea why is it happening, all i know is the method activated is determined by the object type.

Hope someone could explain me what's different here... Thanks!

Comment: You haven't overriden `A#equals`. You've overloaded it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i feel dumb now... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on your answer, for future readers:

In `A.toString()` you call `this.equals(five)`, where `five` is of type `A`.

In the context of A, the only `equals()` method matching `A` is `A.equals(Object o)`. So that is the method the JVM calls.

*If there were an overriding method `B.equals(Object o)`* then this would have been called. It's not enough that there is a `B.equals()` method with a narrower type.

You can get the behaviour you expected by either supplying an `A.equals(A a)` method, or by expanding the breadth of `B.equals()` to take `Object`.

A couple of notes:

- In only a few lines you've created something pretty intricate here. I hope it's just to experiment: real code should be much more straightforward.
- If you're going to implement `equals()` make it accept `Object`, so you're overriding the standard method.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment given explained, i didn't override the function, i overloaded the function with a whole new signature to the method.